# Trouble getting alert to pop up in swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, action, alert

This function is called in my `viewDidLoad`.  It doesn't get an error but nothing ever happens.  It is definitely getting called though because I told it to print and it worked.

Here is the code for alert:

```
func makeAlert()
    {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: "Message", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        // Create the actions
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("OK Pressed")
        }
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) {
        UIAlertAction in
        NSLog("Cancel Pressed")
        }
        // Add the actions
        alertController.addAction(okAction)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
        // Present the controller
        self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Try to call makeAlert() in ViewDidAppear.

Comment: That worked thanks so much

Comment: Glad it works , Don't put much code in viewDidLoad else it will delay to transition of view .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to display your *alertController* before the presenting view controller (the one with your viewDidLoad) is displayed on screen. `viewDidLoad()` is called after your view controller is loaded into memory, not necessarily when its view is in the view hierarchy.

Therefore, call `makeAlert()` in `viewDidAppear(_:)`:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    makeAlert()
}
```

This ensures that your view controller is already displayed and is able to present your *alertController*.

Reading about `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear(_:)` here is helpful: 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/